# Pygame the best way to slow down the framerate of a certain animation without pausing the program?

Tags: animation, pygame, wait, python-3.7

Ive been having a problem with animating different frames of a sprite. My program runs at 60 FPS and some of my sprites dont have nearly enough frames to look smooth and give enough time to be visible to the user. For example my explosion sprite, has 6 frames in it. While the game runs at 60FPS, this means that the whole animation is only visible for 1/10 of a second.

I have already tried the following functions: Pygame.wait and Pygame.delay and the "//" floor function. Pygame.wait/delay both completely pause the program which will mean that just to see the explosion the user would have to stop whatever they are doing and I don't want to have to duplicate frames to come to 30 or 60 frames, that just seems inefficient.

Explosion array:

```
Expl = [pygame.image.load("EX1.png"),pygame.image.load("EX2.png"),pygame.image.load("EX3.png"),pygame.image.load("EX4.png"),pygame.image.load("EX5.png"),pygame.image.load("EX6.png")]
```

Where it happens:

```
            if self.explosionc + 1 >= 6:
                self.explosionc = 0
            elif self.vel > 0:
                win.blit(Expl[self.explosionc // 5],(self.x,self.y))
                self.explosionc +=1
```

The player class, if you need that much info

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.health = 10
        self.visible = True
        self.explosions = False
        self.explosionc = 0
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 5,self.y + 10,60,60)
        self.canshoot = True
        self.dead = False
    def draw(self,win):
        global bgvel
        if self.y > 600:
            win.blit(EFTNA,(self.x,self.y))
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.vel = 2
                #bgvel = 1
        elif self.y <= 600 and self.y > 400:
            win.blit(EFTAL,(self.x,self.y))
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.vel = 3
                #bgvel = 2
        elif self.y <= 400 and self.y > 350:
            win.blit(EFTAM,(self.x,self.y))
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.vel = 4
                #bgvel = 3
        elif self.y <= 450:
            win.blit(EFTAH,(self.x,self.y))
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.vel = 5
                #bgvel = 4
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 5,self.y + 10,60,60)
        #pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0),self.hitbox,2)
        if self.y + self.height > HEIGHT:
            self.y -= self.vel
        if self.x < 0:
            self.x += self.vel
        if self.x + self.width > WIDTH:
            self.x -= self.vel
        if self.explosions == True:
            print("I exploded")
            self.canshoot = False
            self.dead = True
            index = self.explosionc//10
            if self.vel > 0:
                win.blit(Expl[index % 6],(self.x,self.y))
                self.explosionc += 1
                #if self.explosionc >= 6*10:
                #    self.explosionc = 0

            self.visible = False
    def hit(self):
        if self.health > 0:
                self.health -=1
        else:

                self.explosions = True
```

I expect the program to wait a certain amount of time between each frame without pausing the entire program. I have heard that "flooring" is a good way to do this but it just doesn't seem to be effective as it either makes it completely invisible to the human eye or no effect.

Comment: you could use [pygame.time.get_ticks](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to control when to change displayed frame. At start of animation you get current time using `pygame.time.get_ticks` and later in every loop you get time (also using `pygame.time.get_ticks`) and calculate difference. if it is expected value then you change frame and you keep current time to compare with time in next loop.

Comment: you can also use [pygame.time.set_timer](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to create own event every few seconds/miliseconds. And then you can use this event to change frame in animation.

Comment: What does `self.dead` and  `self.visible` do? Shouldn't the states be changed after the explosion rather than at the begin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` to use time to control how long you display frame

```
start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

while running:

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time - start_time >= expected_delay_in_ms:
        change_frame_in_animation()
        start_time = current_time
```

I create `start_time` before `while running` but you have to create it when you start animation.

---

You can also use `pygame.time.set_timer()` to create own event every few miliseconds. And then you can use this event to change frame in animation

```
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+1, expected_delay_in_ms)

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type = pygame.USEREVENT+1:
            change_frame_in_animation()
```

I use `pygame.time.set_timer()` before `while running` but you have to use it when you start animation.

---

**EDIT:** Using your new code in question it could be (but I can't test it)

In `self.__init__` I define

```
self.frame_delay = 200 # 200 milliseconds
```

When player die I set `self.start_delay = 0` - it should display first frame without delay.

```
    def hit(self):
        if self.health > 0:
           self.health -= 1
        else:
           self.explosions = True
           self.start_delay = 0 # or pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

In `draw` I use `self.start_delay` to compare with `current_time` and `self.frame_delay`

```
        if self.explosions == True:

            current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            if current_time - self.start_delay >= self.frame_delay:
                self.start_delay = current_time

                print("I exploded")
                self.canshoot = False
                self.dead = True

                self.explosionc = (self.explosionc + 1) % 6
                if self.vel > 0: # ???
                    win.blit(Expl[self.explosionc],(self.x,self.y))

            self.visible = False
```

I calculate next frame with

```
self.explosionc = (self.explosionc + 1) % 6
```

I don't know only why you use `if self.vel > 0:`

Full code

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.health = 10
        self.visible = True
        self.explosions = False
        self.explosionc = 0
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 5,self.y + 10,60,60)
        self.canshoot = True
        self.dead = False

        self.frame_delay = 200 # 200 milliseconds


    def draw(self,win):
        global bgvel

        if self.y > 600:
            win.blit(EFTNA,(self.x,self.y))
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.vel = 2
                #bgvel = 1
        elif self.y <= 600 and self.y > 400:
            win.blit(EFTAL,(self.x,self.y))
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.vel = 3
                #bgvel = 2
        elif self.y <= 400 and self.y > 350:
            win.blit(EFTAM,(self.x,self.y))
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.vel = 4
                #bgvel = 3
        elif self.y <= 450:
            win.blit(EFTAH,(self.x,self.y))
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.vel = 5
                #bgvel = 4
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 5,self.y + 10,60,60)
        #pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0),self.hitbox,2)

        if self.y + self.height > HEIGHT:
            self.y -= self.vel
        if self.x < 0:
            self.x += self.vel
        if self.x + self.width > WIDTH:
            self.x -= self.vel

        if self.explosions == True:

            current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            if current_time - self.start_delay >= self.frame_delay:
                self.start_delay = current_time

                print("I exploded")
                self.canshoot = False
                self.dead = True

                self.explosionc = (self.explosionc + 1) % 6

                if self.vel > 0: # ???
                    win.blit(Expl[self.explosionc],(self.x,self.y))

            self.visible = False

    def hit(self):
        if self.health > 0:
           self.health -= 1
        else:
           self.explosions = True
           self.start_delay = 0 # or pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

Comment: For solution 1 I see what you mean but im not sure how I would go about implementing this "change_frame_in_animation()"

Comment: You have to get next frame and blit it - so probably `self.explosionc = (self.explosionc + 1) % 6` and `win.blit(Expl[self.explosionc],(self.x,self.y))`